# How to load FilePath into UIWebbview in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, core-data, uiwebview, nsurl

I want to load the html file which i have saved in Core Data.
it is getting something like this in the NSString :

file:///Users/rajeevrajani/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/1339BAA2-127D-4C0C-8C35-5ADA33C46A70/DemoApp.app/0Dosing.html

I want to Load this into UIWebview.
How to do that?

Comment: Please do some research before posting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString   = @"//filepath.html";  // get your file path here
NSURL *webPageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webPageURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
[_webView loadRequest:request]; // _webView is the UIWebView Outlet
```

Answer (score 0):

research before posting question.

```
   NSString *htmlFile = //ur file path put here...
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

its may be helpful to you Thanks.